# Why is my mysql database timestamp changing by itself?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys quick question, I have an entry that I put in my database, and as I echo the value, the value in the database stays the same while the data echoed keeps increasing, which is messing up my function. If anyone knows whats going down, would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<?php
include("../includes/connection.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM points LEFT JOIN users ON points.user_id=users.id WHERE points.topic_id='82' AND users.username='gman'";
$check=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($check)){
    $points_id=$row['points_id'];
    echo $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT *` is generally not a good idea. Also we are going to have a hard time on this without seeing the schema in play.

Comment: /points:/ 4 fields user_id, points_id, topic_id, timestamp
/users:/ id, username etc. Where all points fields are INTS and under username id is INT, username is VARCHAR. I hope that helps, I am not fully sure what you mean by schema

Comment: Can you update Schema Defination in your question itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were duplicate fields, so it was selecting all over the place. I changed the select * to select points.points_id,points.timestamp